# QML: how to scroll scrollview using the mouse wheel

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I need to ensure that the ListView scrolls not only when hovering over it, but also in the area around it. As in the picture
[image]

I tried to do it like this, but scrolling with the mouse wheel still doesn't work

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Rectangle {
    height: 400
    width: 300
    color: "steelblue"
    
    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        wheelEnabled: true
        
        ListView {
            id: listView
            anchors { fill: parent; margins: 40}
            
            clip: true
            
            model: appModel
            
            delegate: Rectangle {
                height: 50
                width: listView.width
                color: colorR
            }
        }
    }
    
    ListModel {
        id: appModel
        
        ListElement { colorR: "red"}
        ListElement { colorR: "green"}
        ListElement { colorR: "blue"}
        ListElement { colorR: "cyan"}
        ListElement { colorR: "yellow"}
        ListElement { colorR: "blue"}
        ListElement { colorR: "lightgray"}
        ListElement { colorR: "red"}
        ListElement { colorR: "green"}
        ListElement { colorR: "blue"}
        ListElement { colorR: "cyan"}
        ListElement { colorR: "yellow"; }
        ListElement { colorR: "lightgray"}
    }
}
```

Comment: why won't you fill what area with the listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WheelHandler` outside the `ListView`

```js
import QtQuick 
import QtQuick.Controls 

Rectangle {
    height: 400
    width: 300
    color: "green"
    function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }
    WheelHandler {
        onWheel: (event)=>{listView.flick(0, event.angleDelta.y*event.y)}
        
    }
    
    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors { fill: parent; margins: 40}            
        model: 50
        spacing: 10
        
        delegate: Rectangle {
            height: 50
            width: listView.width
            color: getRandomColor()
        }
    }
}
```

[You can try this online.](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)